# Rendering datetime_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

Current form code:

```
<%= form_for @booking do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
    <time class="field">
        <%= f.label :date %>
        <%= f.datetime_select :date_time, :prompt => { :hour => "Hour", :minute => "Minute" } %>
    </time>
<% end %>
```

This renders each select item in a new row.

I couldn't post the image due to my noob StackOverflow status but I'll try to display it in interpretative text:

```
select year

select month

select day

...and so on with time.
```

Is there a simple way to render these fields in the same row ie date selectors in one row, time selectors in the next?

```
select year | select month | select day
```

Rendered html:

```
<time class="field">
<option value="2006">2006</option>
...edited for legibility...
<option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>
<select id="booking_date_time_2i" name="booking[date_time(2i)]">

<option value="1">January</option>
...edited for legibility...
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select id="booking_date_time_3i" name="booking[date_time(3i)]">

<option value="1">1</option>
...edited for legibility...
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
 &mdash; <select id="booking_date_time_4i" name="booking[date_time(4i)]">
<option value="">Hour</option>
<option value="00">00</option>
...edited for legibility...
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
 : <select id="booking_date_time_5i" name="booking[date_time(5i)]">
<option value="">Minute</option>
<option value="00">00</option>
...edited for legibility...
<option value="59">59</option>
</select>

</time>
```

Comment: This is a CSS issue. Please provide the resulting HTML structure so we can show you the needed CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the standard datetime_select helper, I would build a helper method with the select statements you wanted and styled the way you wanted.

Here is the link to the docs for the select view method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Just create the select statements to have the id and name values you need (ie booking_date_time_2i for month, 4i for hour etc...), and put them all in a helper so you can easily call them.